# Show a bootstrap modal over a set of popovers

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-popover

I have a jsf page with some bootstrap popovers. These popovers are draggable, using jQuery for that.

When I click on a button to show a modal, it's shown on the screen, but the popovers keep showing over the modal. Here is an image that illustrates my thing.

[image: As you can see, the popovers are over the modal.]

I realized that on bootstrap.css, the z-index of popover is greater than modal (the first is **1060** and the second **1050**). I tried to alter the z-index of the modal, setting a bigger value, but it didn't work.

So, I'm wondering if somebody just faced this problem.

Comment: after modifying did you check indexes again? if it was affected in real execution too

Comment: If you are using jQuery draggable, you might want to look into that. The z-index can be set by jQuery. $( ".selector" ).draggable({ zIndex: 100 });

Comment: My bad. I was editing the bootstrap.css, but included bootstrap.min.css on my page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It most certainly has to do with the z-index. Use the inspector of your browser to figure out if your z-index is really applied. If not, maybe set the attribute to important:

```
.modal {
  z-index: 2000 !important;
}
```

It always depends on the context if you can successfully overwrite a CSS style (which position, how specific the selector is, etc)